# How to install pnpx

Tags: pnpm

I installed pnpm on linux with

```
curl -fsSL https://get.pnpm.io/install.sh | sh -
```

as explained at https://pnpm.io/installation . With this I got just pnpm but no pnpx installed. How can I install pnpx?

Since pnpx is deprecated, can it be that it does not exist anymore?
see https://pnpm.io/pnpx-cli

Answer (score 23):

We're planning to deprecate pnpx. Use [pnpm dlx](https://pnpm.io/cli/dlx) and [pnpm exec](https://pnpm.io/cli/exec) instead of pnpx. You may create an alias in your shell if you still want to call `pnpx` instead of `pnpm dlx`:

```
alias pnpx='pnpm dlx'
```

Also, for now `pnpx` is installed using the installation methods described [here](https://pnpm.io/installation#nodejs-is-preinstalled)

> On Linux or macOS:
>
> ```
> curl -f https://get.pnpm.io/v6.16.js | node - add --global pnpm
> ```
>
> On Windows (PowerShell):
>
> ```
> Invoke-WebRequest 'https://get.pnpm.io/v6.16.js' -UseBasicParsing -o pnpm.js; node pnpm.js add --global pnpm; Remove-Item pnpm.js
> ```

Or using npm `npm i -g pnpm`.

Comment: hey Zoltan, I guess windows is the poor cousin here, but when I follow the instructions to install pnpm via powershell, it (a) appears to install in the current directory , wherever you are at the time (b) doesn't add itself to the system path.  Which means its not really "installed" at all !  I'm assuming the full story is to execute the Invoke-WebRequest in a definite directory which is either already in the path, or can be added to the path ?

Comment: I think it worked for me. File an issue here: https://github.com/pnpm/get.pnpm.io

Alternatively, you can use pnpm via corepack (since Node.js 16) https://github.com/pnpm/get.pnpm.io

`corepack enable && corepack prepare pnpm@6.32.3 --activate`

Comment: Looks as if `pnpx` has been deprecated around pnpm version 8.10 or so. `pnpx` was no longer available when I upgraded. I replace `pnpx` with `pnpm dlx` as suggested by @ZoltanKochan and that worked like a charm.